# Get system mouse state in java (wait, hand, arrow and other)

Tags: java, swing

I am try to write a small  auto click soft to do something myself(click in some location on browser). But when using class java robot , i need to set the delay time, it not truth in every time because the time change with the perfomance of computer. So i think about how to get the current state of the system cursor. Have anyway to do it?

Comment: Can it be done? Yes, but I think that it would be difficult if not impossible in core Java since you're trying to get the state of the OS, something that Java is not good at doing. Likely you'll need to use JNI or JNA or some other utility that can get the OS's state and integrate this with your Java program. Either that or use a different language entirely, one that can get closer to the OS.

Comment: @AlphaWolf There are some System hook libaries (You can google for it).
Like this one for exmaple (there are probably better ones): http://kra.lc/blog/2016/02/java-global-system-hook/ or https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook . Most of them can#t get the State of the mouse tho i guess

Comment: @ScriptKiddy thank for anwser but i think it cant, because in the "read me":Using the GlobalMouseHook class a GlobalMouseListener or the adapter class GlobalMouseAdapter can be registered to listen to mousePressed, mouseReleased, mouseMoved and mouseWheel events.  So, it not contain check mouse state(shape).

Comment: @AlphaWolf Great, hope it works :)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, i tried to write a function in C and it work, but it too decomplex to include to my swing application, that only way i know is run it as a independence program and take the result to my app.

Comment: sorry @ScriptKiddy i was wrong typed, and i am editted, i think it cant, but i wll try(my domitory netowrk need approved to download so  i m still waiting) @@